# GET Request route MEAN

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm creating a MEAN APP and upon registration I want to check if an email already exists. However the GET request doesn't show anything. Also no error.

server.js

```
...
// Set user routes
const userRoutes = require('./user/user_controller');
app.use('/user', userRoutes);
...'
```

user_controller.js

```
router.get('/:email', (req, res) => {
console.log('Requesting user');
User.findOne({'email': req.params.email})
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error getting the post');
        } else {
            res.send(user);
        }
    });
});
```

The GET route never enters because I also don't see the console.log at the beginning of the route. I expect the route to work when I call localhost/user?email=email

I have a POST route whih works perfectly for localhost/user - just to compare

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
user = req.body;
// Validation
req.checkBody('firstName', "Enter a valid firstname").exists().isAlpha();
req.checkBody('lastName', 'Enter a valid lastname').exists().isAlpha();
req.checkBody('email', 'Enter a valid email').exists().isEmail();
req.checkBody('password', 'Enter a valid password').exists().isLength({min:8});

const errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors) {
    res.json({errors: errors});
} else {
    User.create(user)
    .then((user) => res.send(user));
}
});
```

Comment: You are using params then you would call it like `localhost/user/someemail`. When you are calling `localhost/user?email=email` your route never matches the route provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your route the wrong way,

You can do one of these things.

**1) Change your route path to `/`**
As you said you were calling it `localhost/user?email=email` because this matches the route path `/` not `/:email` and you can access  it like `req.query.email`.

**2) Change the way you're calling it**
If you want to use with `/:email` route path call it like `localhost/user/someemail`.